# Should we check front-end JavaScript code for vulnerabilities?

Tags: javascript, security, frontend, static-analysis

I've recently joined the software security world and one thing is bugging my mind.

Is there value in scanning front-end JavaScript code for vulnerabilities with a SAST tool?
My question here is only the code that we write, not OSS dependencies, which are a completely different subject, so forget about shady dependencies that steal your session cookies

My point here is: even the most secure code can be easily changed from the client, if the client wants to make your front-end upside down, they can. And everything accessible from the front-end, the client itself already has access to it, there's no "additional power", or there is?

Is there any inherit vulnerability that can be exposed/mitigated by a front-end JavaScript code?

If we teach a kid to code in JS, and then ask for he/she do the code for us, what could go wrong (from a security perspective) ?

The things I could think of are:

- hardcoded sensitive information/secrets
- write some crazy regex that could take forever to evaluate something and make the webpage freeze for a client depending on the input (but it seems to me that's more of a bug than a vulnerability. Whole different matter when this happens in server-side where it leave your application unresponsive for all clients)
- ???? that's all I got.

Comment: If we’re talking about “vulnerabilities”, I cannot think of any (except secret key in code of course) that does not involve backend.

Comment: If not for vulnerability but for runtime safety, then hell yeah. ESLint to TypeScript, or even some compiled-to-js lang, they all try hard to prevent runtime bug via static analysis.